# Maven profiles and install

Tags: maven-2, build, profile

If I have Maven builds set up for an app with profiles set up for different environments (say like prod vs. dev, defining different DB settings and stuff like that) the 'install' goal doesn't seem to make sense, as I don't know which environment got installed into my repo - I've just got com.example.myproject:myapp:0.0.1.

Have I misunderstood something, or are profiles supposed to be used with other goals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could use the `classifier` attribute so that each profile creates a jar with the classifier, i.e. a unique jar for each environment.  Here is a code snippet to illustrate this.  When run with the `dev` profile (`mvn -P dev install`), it creates a jar with `-dev` classifier, like `myapp-dev-0.0.1.jar`

```
<project>
...
    <properties>
        <env></env>
    </properties>
...

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${env}</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        ...
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
            ...
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You run the usual mvn commands and can select the appropriate profile with -P http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html So it dependends on which profile you chose, what gets installed in the repository.

Comment: Yup, that's the problem - there's a version in there with an invisible customisation as far as clients are concerned. Looking through more docs suggests a 'classifier' property... looking into that...