# How to deploy a Maven WAR to JBoss EAP 6.3 within Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss

I have read every page that shows up on the first Google result page with that search. But nothing seems to help.

Of course I can run "mvn clean install" in or out of Eclipse and get the .war generated in the target folder. I can copy the .war in the deployments folder of JBoss installation myself. And then I can start the server through the server adapter in Eclipse.

But I want that "manual copy of war" to be automatic as well.

How can I do this? What do I need to do to add a new item to "Run As" menu, say, "Maven JBoss Deploy" where underneath, it does a clean, install, deploy (copy to deployments)?

I have Maven 3.1.1 installed separately (outside of Eclipse) and I have told Eclipse where my Maven is. I have JBoss Tools (latest version) installed with JBoss Maven Integration part of it.

I just don't see any way to integrate JBoss and Maven within Eclipse :(

Comment: which jboss tools you have? For luna, you'd need the new [beta version](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/), stable one won't work.

Comment: Yes I do have the beta version that's meant for Luna. I had the stable Kepler-compatible one earlier, but even after updating to beta, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You can do with fileName tag

```
 <fileName>${basedir}/target/webapp.war</fileName> in pom.xml
```

or

You can go with Profiles in pom.xml

[More 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656946/maven-profiles-and-install) 
[More 2](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: how would profiles help with getting a deploy menu item in eclipse?

Comment: You could specify jboss profile(full-ha,full,..),jboss management console username/password,profile mode(Dev,Testing,Production).I'll  update profile tag soon

Comment: you can do that without maven profiles as well. But I don't see how that helps with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, I was able to get Eclipse to deploy a maven project WAR on JBoss.

I just needed to have "Dynamic Web Module" facet attached to the project. I did that using the Project properties in eclipse.

Now I am able to right click the project and Run As Server and that deploys to JBoss. And the project is still a Maven project. Yay!